# Intel TBB program does not terminate, possible misuuse of reference counter

Tags: c++, tbb

I have the following TBB code snippet. The code does not work as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tbb/mutex.h>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace tbb;

tbb::mutex printLock;

class Task1 : public task {
public:
  task* execute() {
    printLock.lock();
    cout << "Task 1 start" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    printLock.lock();
    cout << "Task 1 end" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    return NULL;
  }
};

class Task2 : public task {
public:
  task* execute() {
    printLock.lock();
    cout << "Task 2 start" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    printLock.lock();
    cout << "Task 2 end" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    return NULL;
  }
};

class Task5 : public task {
public:
  task* execute() {
    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "Task 5 start" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "T5:Sleep start" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();
    sleep(10);
    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "T5:Sleep end" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "Task 5 end" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    return NULL;
  }
};

class Task4 : public task {
public:
  task* execute() {
    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "Task 4 start" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    set_ref_count(1); // Create a child but do not want to wait

    task& u = *new (task::allocate_child()) Task5();
    task::spawn(u);

    // task::wait_for_all(); // Task 5 is asynchronous, just to print

    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "Task 4 end" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    return NULL;
  }
};

class Task3 : public task {
public:
  task* execute() {
    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "Task 3 start" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    set_ref_count(2);

    task& u = *new (task::allocate_child()) Task4();
    task::spawn(u);

    task::wait_for_all();

    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "Task 3 end" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    return NULL;
  }
};

class Root1 : public task {
public:
  task* execute() {
    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "Root1 start" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    set_ref_count(4);

    task& a = *new (task::allocate_child()) Task1();
    task& v = *new (task::allocate_child()) Task3();
    task& b = *new (task::allocate_child()) Task2();

    task::spawn(a);
    task::spawn(v);
    task::spawn(b);

    task::wait_for_all();

    printLock.lock();
    std::cout << "Root1 end" << std::endl;
    printLock.unlock();

    return NULL;
  }
};

int main() {
  task& v = *new (task::allocate_root()) Root1();
  task::spawn_root_and_wait(v);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I expect to the see the following (or similar) output. Task 5 may start, may finish, it does not matter.

```
Root 1 start 
Task 2 start
Task 2 end
Task 3 start
Task 4 start
Task 4 end
Task 3 end
Task 5 start
T5:Sleep start
Task 1 start
Task 1 end
T5:Sleep end
Task 5 end
Root 1 end
```

However, the code runs possibly infinitely (?) with Tasks 3, 4, and 5 repeated.

```
Root 1 start
Task 2 start
Task 2 end
Task 3 start
Task 4 start
Task 4 end
Task 3 end
Task 5 start
T5:Sleep start
Task 1 start
Task 1 end
T5:Sleep end
Task 5 end
Task 4 start
Task 4 end
Task 3 start
Task 4 start
Task 4 end
Task 5 start
T5:Sleep start
Task 5 start
T5:Sleep start
Task 5 start
T5:Sleep start
T5:Sleep end
Task 5 end
Task 4 start
Task 4 end
Task 5 start
T5:Sleep start
T5:Sleep end
T5:Sleep end
Task 5 end
Task 5 start
Task 5 end
Task 4 start
Task 4 end
Task 5 start
T5:Sleep start
Task 5 start
T5:Sleep start
T5:Sleep start
^C
```

I do not understand the example fully, the error possibly is related to the manipulation of `set_ref_count()`. Any pointers to help understand the issue will help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a debug version of the TBB library? It has internal asserts in various places, which can indicate incorrect use of the library and shed light on the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is near asynchronous task. When Task 5 finishes, it signals Task 4 to decrement its refcount that reaches zero and Task 4 is run again. So, there is a loop. As a result it leads to a race on refcount of Task 3 that causes an additional loop. For asynchronous pattern, you need to use continuation passing approach.
However, I would recommend using several `tbb::task_group` algorithms to simply the synchronization issues.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting.